# Get innerText from XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys, I have an XML file I need to parse, but only for the text, not the HTML. Here's an example of a node:

```
<highlights><![CDATA[<ul style="color:#000000;font-size:small;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif"><li>Classy &amp; elegant purse hooks</li><li>Choose from various styles<br></li><li>Stable and reliable</li><li>Makes a great gift!  </li></ul>  ]]></highlights>
```

As you can see, the CDATA has HTML code in it, so when I do element.Value I also get the tags. Is there any simple way to get just the text?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data in CDATA is not valid XML, you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the result:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var html = xdoc.Descendants("highlights").First().Value;

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Output:

> Classy & elegant purse hooksChoose
>   from various stylesStable and
>   reliableMakes a great gift!

Comment: That looks very cpu intensive. Would that have a lot of overhead involved? (I would have to run through at least 300 like that)

Comment: I can't come up with any alternative that would be cleaner though - do you have the option of changing the format you work with to begin with? That could probably simplify a lot.

Comment: It is sent to me in XML but I can use any framework to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

```
<literal id="continer"  runat="server"/>

continer.text=@"<highlights><![CDATA[<ul style="color:#000000;font-size:small;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif"><li>Classy &amp; elegant purse hooks</li><li>Choose from various styles<br></li><li>Stable and reliable</li><li>Makes a great gift!  </li></ul>  ]]></highlights> ";
```

or

```
<div id="continer" runat="server"/>

continer.innerHtml==@"<highlights><![CDATA[<ul style="color:#000000;font-size:small;font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif"><li>Classy &amp; elegant purse hooks</li><li>Choose from various styles<br></li><li>Stable and reliable</li><li>Makes a great gift!  </li></ul>  ]]></highlights> ";
```